# Arrange a duplicate object in a Javascript array to produce one value

Tags: javascript, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to arrange my current object, which looks like below

```
var myValues = [
{
    client: "FIRE",
    firstname: "Test",
    id: "test@fire.com",
    arrangeid: "FIREFOX",
    region: "FOP",
    secondname: "Testy",
    status: "Approved"
},
{
    client: "FIRE",
    firstname: "Test",
    id: "test@fire.com",
    arrangeid: "BUZZZZZZ",
    region: "FOP",
    secondname: "Testy",
    status: "Approved"
},
{
    client: "PANTER",
    firstname: "Panty",
    id: "panty@panter.com",
    arrangeid: "PANTER",
    region: "PAN",
    secondname: "mc panty",
    status: "Approved"
},
{
    client: "BAT",
    firstname: "Bruce",
    id: "bat@bat.com",
    arrangeid: "BLACKBAT",
    region: "BLK",
    secondname: "Wyne",
    status: "Approved"
}

]
```

So I've got this object, the first two ID's are the same but they got different arrangeid. I wanna be able to join the them to gather them together. Where the object looks something like this:

```
    var myValues = [
{
    client: "FIRE",
    firstname: "Test",
    id: "test@fire.com",
    arrangeid: ["BUZZZZZZ", "FIREFOX"],
    region: "FOP",
    secondname: "Testy",
    status: "Approved"
},
{
    client: "PANTER",
    firstname: "Panty",
    id: "panty@panter.com",
    arrangeid: ["PANTER"],
    region: "PAN",
    secondname: "mc panty",
    status: "Approved"
},
{
    client: "BAT",
    firstname: "Bruce",
    id: "bat@bat.com",
    arrangeid: ["BLACKBAT"],
    region: "BLK",
    secondname: "Wyne",
    status: "Approved"
}

]
```

I have a jsfidle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ronoc4/5qn6o7mf/), where i kinda get a result. Can it be done better, cleaner. Have I approached it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), **[`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)** and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like this:

```js
var myValues = [{client:"FIRE",firstname:"Test",id:"test@fire.com",arrangeid:"FIREFOX",region:"FOP",secondname:"Testy",status:"Approved"},{client:"FIRE",firstname:"Test",id:"test@fire.com",arrangeid:"BUZZZZZZ",region:"FOP",secondname:"Testy",status:"Approved"},{client:"PANTER",firstname:"Panty",id:"panty@panter.com",arrangeid:"PANTER",region:"PAN",secondname:"mc panty",status:"Approved"},{client:"BAT",firstname:"Bruce",id:"bat@bat.com",arrangeid:"BLACKBAT",region:"BLK",secondname:"Wyne",status:"Approved"}];

const merged = myValues.reduce((acc, a) => {
  acc[a.client] = acc[a.client] || { ...a, arrangeid: [] };
  acc[a.client].arrangeid.push(a.arrangeid);
  return acc;
},{})

const output = Object.values(merged);
console.log(output)
```

The accumulator is an object with each unique `client` as its key so that it's easier to group them.

```
{
  "FIRE": {
    "client": "FIRE",
    "firstname": "Test",
    "id": "test@fire.com",
    "arrangeid": [ "FIREFOX", "BUZZZZZZ" ],
    "region": "FOP",
    "secondname": "Testy",
    "status": "Approved"
  },
  "PANTER": {
    "client": "PANTER",
    "id": "panty@panter.com",
    "arrangeid": [
      "PANTER"
    ],
   ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()`

```js
var myValues = [
{
    client: "FIRE",
    firstname: "Test",
    id: "test@fire.com",
    arrangeid: "FIREFOX",
    region: "FOP",
    secondname: "Testy",
    status: "Approved"
},
{
    client: "FIRE",
    firstname: "Test",
    id: "test@fire.com",
    arrangeid: "BUZZZZZZ",
    region: "FOP",
    secondname: "Testy",
    status: "Approved"
},
{
    client: "PANTER",
    firstname: "Panty",
    id: "panty@panter.com",
    arrangeid: "PANTER",
    region: "PAN",
    secondname: "mc panty",
    status: "Approved"
},
{
    client: "BAT",
    firstname: "Bruce",
    id: "bat@bat.com",
    arrangeid: "BLACKBAT",
    region: "BLK",
    secondname: "Wyne",
    status: "Approved"
}

]



let res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myValues)).reduce((ac,a) => {
  let ind = ac.findIndex(x => x.id === a.id);
  a.arrangeid = [a.arrangeid];
  ind === -1 ? ac.push(a) : ac[ind].arrangeid.push(...a.arrangeid);
  return ac;
},[])
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Map to key the objects by their id, and then populate the `arrangeid` arrays:

```js
const myValues = [{client: "FIRE",firstname: "Test",id: "test@fire.com",arrangeid: "FIREFOX",region: "FOP",secondname: "Testy",status: "Approved"},{client: "FIRE",firstname: "Test",id: "test@fire.com",arrangeid: "BUZZZZZZ",region: "FOP",secondname: "Testy",status: "Approved"}, {client: "PANTER",firstname: "Panty",id: "panty@panter.com",arrangeid: "PANTER",region: "PAN",secondname: "mc panty",status: "Approved"},{client: "BAT",firstname: "Bruce",id: "bat@bat.com",arrangeid: "BLACKBAT",region: "BLK",secondname: "Wyne",status: "Approved"}];

const map = new Map(myValues.map(o => [o.id, {...o, arrangeid: []}]));
myValues.forEach(o => map.get(o.id).arrangeid.push(o.arrangeid));
const result = [...map.values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

For larger data sets, you can use the lookup capabilities of a `Map` object to collect all the items for each id and then you can convert that result into whatever format you want.  You can run this snippet to see the result.

```js
function collectByField(data, key, prop) {
    const collection = new Map();
    for (const obj of data) {
         let item = collection.get(obj[key]);
         if (item) {
             // add this item's property to the array
             item[prop].push(obj[prop]);
         } else {
             // put a copy of our object into the Map
             // convert prop to an array with one initial item in it
             let copy = Object.assign({}, obj);
             copy[prop] = [obj[prop]];
             collection.set(obj[key], copy);
         }
    }
    // now use the Set to create final array output
    return Array.from(collection.values());
}

let myValues = [
{
    client: "FIRE",
    firstname: "Test",
    id: "test@fire.com",
    arrangeid: "FIREFOX",
    region: "FOP",
    secondname: "Testy",
    status: "Approved"
},
{
    client: "FIRE",
    firstname: "Test",
    id: "test@fire.com",
    arrangeid: "BUZZZZZZ",
    region: "FOP",
    secondname: "Testy",
    status: "Approved"
},
{
    client: "PANTER",
    firstname: "Panty",
    id: "panty@panter.com",
    arrangeid: "PANTER",
    region: "PAN",
    secondname: "mc panty",
    status: "Approved"
},
{
    client: "BAT",
    firstname: "Bruce",
    id: "bat@bat.com",
    arrangeid: "BLACKBAT",
    region: "BLK",
    secondname: "Wyne",
    status: "Approved"
}
];

console.log(collectByField(myValues, "id", "arrangeid"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly more generic approach, which lets you group by any combination of fields and then merge some given ones into an array:

```js
const pick = (fields, obj) => fields.reduce((o, fld) => ({...o, [fld]: obj[fld]}), {})

const groupAndMerge = (groupFields, mergeFields, xs) => 
  Object.values(xs.reduce(
    (a, x, _, __, key = JSON.stringify(pick(groupFields, x))) => 
      (a[key] = (a[key] || []).concat(x)) && a,
    {}
  )).map(xs => ({
    ...xs[0],
    ...mergeFields.reduce((a, f) => ({...a, [f]: xs.map(x => x[f])}), {})
  }))

const myValues = [{arrangeid: "FIREFOX", client: "FIRE", firstname: "Test", fid: "test@fire.com", region: "FOP", secondname: "Testy", status: "Approved"}, {arrangeid: "BUZZZZZZ", client: "FIRE", firstname: "Test", fid: "test@fire.com", region: "FOP", secondname: "Testy", status: "Approved"}, {arrangeid: "PANTER", client: "PANTER", firstname: "Panty", fid: "panty@panter.com", region: "PAN", secondname: "mc panty", status: "Approved"}, {arrangeid: "BLACKBAT", client: "BAT", firstname: "Bruce", fid: "bat@bat.com", region: "BLK", secondname: "Wyne", status: "Approved"}]

const result = groupAndMerge(['client', 'id'], ['arrangeid'], myValues)

console.log(result)
```

The helper function `pick` simply chooses certain properties of the target object, so that `pick(['a', 'c'], {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}) //=> {a: 1, c: 3}`.

`groupAndMerge` uses the first parameter (here `['client', 'id']`) to identify the fields which have to be the same, and the second one (here `['arrangeid']`) to show which ones have to be grouped.

You mention that the first two have the same `id`.  My code checks both `client` and `id`; this is as much as anything a proof-of-concept, but it could be useful.

There is one caveat to using this: it only merges well on string or numeric values.  Some others might work, but I wouldn't count on it.  (That is also true for at least one other answer here, but I don't know if it's important to you.)

The advantage I see to this is that it's only slightly more complex than a bespoke implementation, and it's useful in a number of other circumstances.